# Symfony 1.4 Validation Error Unsigned

Tags: validation, save, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, unsigned

when i try to save an form in Symfony 1.4 it gives me these errors:

```
Validation failed in class CmsContentElementFile
4 fields had validation errors:

* 1 validator failed on title (unsigned)
* 1 validator failed on alt (unsigned)
* 1 validator failed on link (unsigned)
* 2 validators failed on direction (length, unsigned)
```

What does this errors mean?

EDIT:

Validators from the form fields:

```
   $this->setValidators(array(
              'title'      => new sfValidatorString(),
              'alt'        => new sfValidatorString(),
              'link'       => new sfValidatorString(),
              'width'      => new sfValidatorInteger(),
              'height'     => new sfValidatorInteger(),
              'direction'  => new sfValidatorPass()
          ));
```

Comment: And what values did you submit?

Comment: It works with 
title = test
alt = test
link = test
direction = test
I also change the structure from the table that "NULL" is allowed. And one false was that direction is an varchar and i give the field "unsigned: 1".

Comment: So problem fixed? If so post an answer where you described what you've done and then, accept it.

Comment: Not enough Reputation :P Need to wait 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. The Problem was that i give the field "direction" the param "unsigned:1 and it also was an varchar. Well that fix the problem. Hope it helps somebody.